# How to rename files using certain string inside each file?

Tags: regex, bash, macos, awk, grep

I have a list of html files that contain a certain tag in each file as below:

```
<div id="myID" style="display:none">1_34876</div>
```

I would like to search for that tag in each file and rename each file according to the number within that tag, i.e rename the file containing the tag above to 1_34876.html
and so forth..

Is there a regex or bash command using grep or awk that can accomplish this?

So far I was able to grep each file using the following command but stuck on how to rename the files:

```
grep '<div id="myID" style="display:none">.*</div>' ./*.html
```

An additional bonus would be if the command doesn't overwrite duplicate files, e.g. if another file contains the 1_34876 tag above then the second file would be renamed as 1_34876 v2.html or something similar.

Kindly advice if this can be achieved in a way that doesn't require programming.

Many thanks indeed.
Ali

Comment: A shell loop or `find` should do the job. An added bonus is to use a proper html parser.

Comment: Your specification is not complete. What if there are several such tags in a file? What if there is none? What is the exact pattern that matches `1_34876` in your example? What new name do you want if the `div` tag is empty? What if there is a newline in the `div` tag? Or a `/` character (file names cannot contain a `/`)? See? There are several missing "details".

Comment: "Kindly advice if this can be achieved in a way that doesn't require programming."  No. It cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following script to achieve your goal. Note, for the script to work on macOS, you either have to install GNU grep via Homebrew, or substitute the `grep` call with `ggrep`.

- The script will search the current directory and all its subdirectories for `*.html` files.
- It will substitute only the names of the files that contain the specific tag.
- For multiple files that containt the same tag, each subsicuent file apart from the first will have an identifier appended to its name. E.g., `1_234.html`, `1_234_1.html`, `1_234_2.html`
- For files that contain multiple tags, the first tag encountered will be used.

```
#!/bin/bash

rename_file ()
{
    # Check that file name received is an existing regular file
    file_name="$(realpath "${1}")"
    if [ ! -f "${file_name}" ]; then
        echo "No argument or non existing file or non regular file provided"
        exit 1
    fi

    # Get the tag number. If the number does not exist, the variable tag will be
    # empty. The first tag on a file will be used if there are multiple tags
    # within a file.
    tag="$(grep -oP -m 1 '(?<=<div id="myID" style="display:none">).*?(?=</div>)' \
        -- "${file_name}")"

    # Rename the file only if it contained a tag
    if [ -n "${tag}" ]; then
        file_path="$(dirname "${file_name}")"

        # Change directory to the file's location silently
        pushd "${file_path}" > /dev/null || return

        # Check for multiple occurences of files with the same tag
        if [ -e "${tag}.html" ]; then
            counter="$(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${tag}.html" -o -name "${tag}_*.html" | wc -l)"
            tag="${tag}_${counter}"
        fi

        # Rename the file
        mv "${file_name}" "${tag}.html"

        # Return to previous directory silently
        popd > /dev/null || return
    fi

}

# Necessary in order to call rename_file from find command within main
export -f rename_file

# The entry point function of the script. This function searches for all the
# html files in the directory that the script is run, and all subdirectories.
# The function calls rename_files upon each of the found files.
main ()
{
    find ./ -type f -name "*.html" -exec bash -c 'rename_file "${1}"' _ {} \;
}

main
```

Answer (score -1):

As we do not know exact content of the files and folders we need to take care about

1. Check that tag is unique
2. File with such name does not exists
3. Do not rename already renamed files

Steps:

1. Search for files with specidied tags `grep -o '<div id="myID" style="display:none">.*</div>' /*.html`
   it will provide us output in format `file_path:tag`
2. Extract file_path using regexp `[^:]+` (not : one or more symbols )
   with `-o` (exact match) and get first occurence using `head -1`
3. Get new file name from tag using regexp ">.*<" and then remowing "<>" using sed
   we can use here one regexp to skip <> but it will be more complex and not so readable grep -oP ">\K.*(?=<)"
4. Rename files , log Errors  and script actions, return non zero exit code in case of issues
5. Unless it is really required better to use functions with local variables declaration (decalre using `function fn_rename_html_files {}` instead of `fn_rename_html_files() {}` as if we have complex logic with nesting functions you may change other functions variables and debugging will be not so easy)

```
function fn_rename_html_files {
    typeset l_files_path="${1-.}"
    typeset l_html_ext=".html"
    typeset l_proc_exit_code=0
    typeset l_proc_name="${FUNCNAME[0]}"

    typeset l_files_to_search="${l_files_path}/*${l_html_ext}"

    typeset l_tag_reg_exp='<div id="myID" style="display:none" *>.*</div>'
    typeset l_matched_files=$(grep -o "$l_tag_reg_exp" $l_files_to_search | sort -u)
    typeset l_prev_file_path=""

    # loop through matching files
    while IFS= read -r l_file_path_with_match_tag
    do
        l_current_file_path=$(echo "$l_file_path_with_match_tag" | egrep -o "([^:])+" | head -1 )
        l_current_file_name=$(basename "$l_current_file_path")

        #echo "l_current_file_path $l_current_file_path "
        #echo "l_current_file_name $l_current_file_name "

        l_new_file_name_from_tag=$(echo "$l_file_path_with_match_tag" | egrep -o ">.*<" | sed "s/[><]//g" | head -1 )
        l_new_file_name="${l_new_file_name_from_tag}${l_html_ext}"
        l_new_file_path="$l_files_path/$l_new_file_name"

        #echo "$l_new_file_path $l_new_file_path "
        #echo "$l_new_file_name $l_new_file_name "

        if [[ "$l_prev_file_path" == "$l_current_file_path"  ]]; then
            echo "$l_proc_name ERROR: myID tag is not unique for $l_current_file_path, skipping second renaming " >&2
            let l_proc_exit_code+=1
            continue
        fi

        if ! [[ -f "$l_new_file_path" ]]; then
            if mv "$l_current_file_path" "$l_new_file_path" ; then
                echo "$l_proc_name SUCCESS: renamed $l_current_file_path to $l_new_file_path"
            else
                echo "$l_proc_name ERROR: cannot move $l_current_file_path to $l_new_file_path" >&2
                let l_proc_exit_code+=1
            fi
        else
            if [[ "$l_current_file_name" == "$l_new_file_name" ]]; then
                echo "$l_proc_name Warning: File has been already renamed: $l_current_file_name, skipping"
            else
                echo "$l_proc_name Warning: File with such name already exists: $l_current_file_name, skipping" >&2
                let l_proc_exit_code+=1
            fi
        fi

        l_prev_file_path=$l_current_file_path

    done <<< $l_matched_files

    return $l_proc_exit_code
}

# create test files
rm *.html
echo '<div id="myID" style="display:none">1_1</div>' > 1.html ;
echo '<div id="myID" style="display:none">1_2</div>' > 2.html ;
echo '<div id="myID" style="display:none">1_3</div>' > 3.html ;
echo '<div id="myID" style="display:none">1_3_1</div>' >> 3.html ;
# run
fn_rename_html_files
```

[image]

Comment: This has extremely naïve assumptions about the other contents of the HTML files, and broken quoting exacerbated by an `eval`.

Comment: where is it naive ?
it is an exact match for div tag.
I have added echo of command just for debug purpose and to avoid copy paste, used eval. Please provide valuable feed back so that i can improve my code not just emothional stuff

Comment: https://ideone.com/ELx6KO

Comment: 1) According to the author assumption we are searching for unique identifier (myId) and it needs to be unique , otherwise this exercise  with renaming does not make sence.
2) I suppose you mean that here i had "broken quotes", please show how to fix them as here i need to expand variable ?
 l_new_name="$( echo "$l_line" | grep -oP ">\K.*(?=<)" ).html"
 l_new_name=$( echo "$l_line" | grep -oP ">\K.*(?=<)" )".html" <-- this way ?

Comment: Simply `mv "$l_name" "$l_new_name"` avoids storing the command in a variable and thus gets rid of the `eval`. The logic is still brittle because the regex you use to extract the file name requires that the match doesn't contain `html` anywhere. The overall approach still seems unnecessarily complex and error-prone.

Comment: 1) I have added echo of command just for debug purpose. And to avoid copy paste, used eval. It may be required for logging,  here it is redundant. I use this approach to find what has been  moved/deleted by which script in case of issues
2) You didn't get reg exp then as i simply extract everything that is between >< 
it does not have any htm there. Grep gives output as [file_name :  match] and i got file name and id from match. 
Thanks anyway